# CFLOG does not write to log file

Tags: coldfusion

I want to write some information to a log file. I tried adding this code to my file:

```
<cfparam name="BillingAddressOne" default="#session.userinfo.Address1#">
<cfparam name="BillingAddressTwo" default="#session.userinfo.Address2#">
<cfparam name="BillingCity" default="#session.userinfo.city#">
<cfparam name="BillingState" default="#session.userinfo.state#">
<cfparam name="BillingZipCode" default="#session.userinfo.zip#">
<cfparam name="BillingCountry" default="US">
<cfparam name="BillingPhone" default="#session.userinfo.phone#">
<cfparam name="BillingFax" default="#session.userinfo.fax#">
<cfparam name="BillingEmail" default="#session.userinfo.email#">
<cfparam name="CardType" default="#sessioninfo.CreditCardType#">
<cfparam name="form['Credit Card Number']" default="#sessioninfo.CreditCardNumber#">
<cfparam name="expmonth" default="#sessioninfo.CreditCardExpMonth#">
<cfparam name="expyear" default="#sessioninfo.CreditCardExpYear#">
<cfparam name="CCverificationCode" default="#sessioninfo.CCverificationCode#">
<cfparam name="CreditCardName" default="#sessioninfo.CreditCardName#">


<cflog file="info.log" application="no" 
    text="#BillingAddressOne# #BillingAddressTwo# #BillingCity# #BillingState# #BillingZipCode# #BillingCountry# #BillingPhone# #BillingEmail# #pmtmethod# #CardType# #form['Credit Card Number']# #expmonth# #expyear# #CCverificationCode# #CreditCardName#">
```

I tried inputting something but nothing shows in file `info.log`

Comment: thank @Leigh, i tried this, but nothing in file info.log. can you help me

Comment: Why don't you start with something a little more basic and try to log some static text.  Then set a variable to a value and try to log that variable.  Then gradually work your way up to what you really want to log.

Comment: thank Dan Bracuk. Now can i use cfset to set variable ?, Can you give a exmaple for my question, thank you very much

Comment: Blaise Swanwick, i tried same you write, but no thing show in file info.log

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_j-l_06.html) the file attribute should only contain the file name, not the extension.

Also,

> The file must be located in the default log directory. You cannot
>   specify a directory path. If the file does not exist, it is created
>   automatically, with the extension .log.

This will most likely be [coldfusion install folder]/logs

Try

```
<cflog file="info"  
       application="no" 
       text="#BillingAddressOne# 
             #BillingAddressTwo# 
             #BillingCity# 
             #BillingState# 
             #BillingZipCode# 
             #BillingCountry# 
             #BillingPhone# 
             #BillingEmail# 
             #pmtmethod# 
             #CardType# 
             #form['Credit Card Number']# 
             #expmonth# 
             #expyear# 
             #CCverificationCode# 
             #CreditCardName#">
```

Comment: i tried add this code to my file, but when i see, info.log nothing in info.log , can you help me

Comment: yes know about that, info.log same directory with my file, can you help me?

Comment: it should NOT be in the same folder as your .cfm file.  it will be in your log folder.

Comment: yes it show in log folder, how do i can create 1 path for info.log